# Unexpected deadlocks in Postgresql (while using psycopg2)

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I am dealing with a deadlock issue in PostgreSQL that I do not understand.
I am trying to implement a Round Robin-like algorithm using Python, psycopg2 module, and a Postgres database.
I want several instances of an application to do the following:
 - Lock the whole table with a list of tasks for a very short interval
 - Pick a task to perform (least recently performed task, with some limitations)
 - Label task so other instances do not pick it (only one instance is allowed to perform the same task at the same time)
 - Unlock table
 - Perform task
 - Repeat
Other sessions should also be able to update certain fields of this table. 
Suddenly, I am getting deadlocks that I cannot explain. I have simplified my Python script as hard as I could, I am performing a Commit after every statement (when possible), but still a deadlock appears every now and then.
 
For some reason, every time I get a deadlock, it is the first statement in a transaction. How is it even possible? My table doesn’t have any triggers, or foreign key constraints, or anything that would make things complicated. The only explanation I can come up with is that PostgreSQL does not release the lock immediately after the commit. Or perhaps it is psycopg2 that is not working the way I expect it to? I have failed to reproduce the issue by manually running statements in different sessions.
Deadlocks are rare, but I do get them at least once every few hours

I am running on PostgreSQL 9.6.1 and Python 2.7.12

Here is the code I run (this is just a simplified sample I made in order to catch the issue):

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import datetime
import time
sys.path.append('/opt/workflow/lib')
import config
import ovs_lib


instance_type='scan_master'
instance_id=sys.argv[1]

dbh=psycopg2.connect(dbname=config.values['pgsql']['db'], host=config.values['pgsql']['host'], port=int(config.values['pgsql']['port']), user=config.values['pgsql']['user'], password=config.values['pgsql']['pass'])
dbh.set_session(isolation_level='READ COMMITTED', autocommit=False)
cursor = dbh.cursor()
cursor.execute("SET search_path TO "+config.values['pgsql']['schema'])

def sanitize(string):
  string=string.replace("'","''")
  return string

def get_task(instance_id):
  task_id=None
  out_struct={}
  instance_id=sanitize(instance_id)
  #Lock whole table
  dbh.commit() #Just in case
  cursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM wf_task FOR UPDATE") #Lock the table
  cursor.execute("UPDATE wf_task SET scanner_instance_id=null WHERE scanner_instance_id='"+instance_id+"'") #release task from previous run
  #Now get the task
  sql ="SELECT t.task_id, st.scanner_function, t.parallel_runs\n"
  sql+="FROM wf_task t\n"
  sql+="JOIN wf_scanner_type st ON t.scanner_type_id=st.scanner_type_id\n"
  sql+="WHERE status='A'\n"
  sql+="AND t.scanner_instance_id is NULL\n"
  sql+="AND last_scan_ts<=now()-scan_interval*interval '1 second'\n"
  sql+="ORDER BY last_scan_ts\n"
  sql+="LIMIT 1\n"
  cursor.execute(sql)
  cnt=cursor.rowcount
  if cnt>0:
    row=cursor.fetchone()
    task_id=row[0]
    sql ="UPDATE wf_task SET scanner_instance_id='"+instance_id+"',last_scan_ts=current_timestamp(3) WHERE task_id="+str(task_id)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    scanner_function=row[1]
    parallel_runs=row[2]
    out_struct['task_id']=task_id
    out_struct['scanner_function']=scanner_function
    out_struct['parallel_runs']=parallel_runs
  dbh.commit()
  return out_struct

def process_task(task_id):
  sql="UPDATE wf_task SET submitted_ts=now() WHERE task_id="+str(task_id)+" AND submitted_ts<now()"
  cursor.execute(sql)
  dbh.commit()
  sql="UPDATE wf_task SET executed_ts=now() WHERE task_id="+str(task_id)+" AND submitted_ts<now()"
  cursor.execute(sql)
  dbh.commit()

while True:
  if not ovs_lib.check_control(instance_type, instance_id):
    now_time=datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print now_time+" Stop sygnal received"
    exit(0)
  task_struct=get_task(instance_id)
  if 'task_id' not in task_struct:
    time.sleep(1)
    continue
  process_task(task_struct['task_id'])
```

And here are examples of the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/workflow/bin/scan_simple.py", line 70, in <module>
process_task(task_struct['task_id'])
  File "/opt/workflow/bin/scan_simple.py", line 58, in process_task
cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError: deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 21577 waits for ShareLock on transaction 39243027; blocked by process 21425.
Process 21425 waits for ShareLock on transaction 39243029; blocked by process 21102.
Process 21102 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on tuple (8,12) of relation 39933 of database 16390; blocked by process 21577.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
CONTEXT:  while updating tuple (8,12) in relation "wf_task"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/workflow/bin/scan_simple.py", line 66, in <module>
    task_struct=get_task(instance_id)
  File "/opt/workflow/bin/scan_simple.py", line 27, in get_task
    cursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM wf_task FOR UPDATE")
psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError: deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 21776 waits for ShareLock on transaction 39488839; blocked by process 21931.
Process 21931 waits for ShareLock on transaction 39488844; blocked by process 21776.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (17,9) in relation “wf_task"
```

At that time I had 6 instances of this script running simultaneously
No other sessions were active in the database.


**Later update**
Today I learned something new about Postgres that its very relevant to this question
Starting version 9.5, PostgreSQL supports a SKIP LOCKED statement, that solves the problem that I was trying to design my application around, and in a very elegant manner
If you are struggling with concurrency in PostgreSQL while trying to implement some sort of queue or round robin solution, you absolutely must read this:
https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/

Comment: An aside to an interesting question, but string concatenating values into queries is a really bad habit. Especially so since [psycopg has excellent placeholder support](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). To quote the docs: "Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint."

Comment: [Here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/optimizing-concurrent-updates-in-postgres) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825663/can-two-select-for-update-statements-on-the-same-table-cause-a-deadlock) it is indicated that an explicit ORDER BY should avoid deadlocks caused by arbitrary row order in your SELECT FOR UPDATE. Also is it possible for you to not lock the whole table, but just the rows involved, e.g. `WHERE scanner_instance_id = instance_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that the sequential scan in the first `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` doesn't always return the rows in the same order, so concurrent executions of this statement lock the rows of the table in different orders. This leads to the deadlock you experience.

There are several solutions, in increasing goodness:

- I think that the technique to lock the whole table for this update is horrible for performance, but if you insist on keeping your code, you could set [`synchronize_seqscans`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-SYNCHRONIZE-SEQSCANS) to `off` so that all sequential scans return the rows in the same order. But you really shouldn't lock all rows in a table like you do, because

  - It causes an unnecessary sequential scan.
  - It is not safe. Somebody could `INSERT` new rows between the time where you lock the rows and the time where you run your `UPDATE`s.
- If you really want to lock the whole table, use the `LOCK TABLE` statement instead of locking all rows in the table. That will get rid of the deadlock as well.
- The best solution is probably to lock the rows with the `UPDATE` itself. To avoid deadlocks, examine the execution plans that PostgreSQL uses for the `UPDATE`. This will be an index scan or a sequential scan. With an index scan you are safe, because that will return the rows in a certain order. For a sequential scan, disable the `synchronize_seqscans` feature mentioned above, ideally only for the transaction:

  ```
  START TRANSACTION;
  SET LOCAL synchronize_seqscans = off;
  /* your UPDATEs go here */
  COMMIT;
  ```

Comment: Thanks Laurenz! It actually makes sense
I will try to use the LOCK TABLE statement instead of SELECT FOR UPDATE. It never occurred to me that Postgres might not lock the whole table at once, but instead lock it a row at a time.. but it would explain its current behavior.
I will leave it running for a while and see if deadlocks appear

Comment: Unfortunately, locking the whole table in this case is the best way to do it. Locking a specific record with an UPDATE will lead to undesired circumstances: i do not know the primary key of the record i want to update; the record my update statement will spot might be already held by another instance (and very likely so - since every instance is looking for the record with the same condition).

Comment: After the lock is released, the conditions will change, and that will no longer be the record i need. I will end up not updating any record (since WHERE clause is not satisfied afer lock is released). So the script ends up waiting for previous transaction anyway, and ends up updating no rows.

Comment: For the use case i have in mind, time between locking table and committing will probably take milliseconds; running process_task function instead of a dummy in the example will probably take 2-3 seconds, so performance deterioration will be negligible.

Comment: The performance impact will *not* be negligible, because that way only one process can work on the table at the same time. But if that solution is good enough for you, that's fine.

Comment: Ok, it has been running for over 24 hours, and there wasn't a single deadlock. Apparently replacing SELECT..FOR UPDATE with LOCK TABLE.. did the trick.Thank you a lot Laurenz.

Comment: I would argue that for this situation, any solution that locks data at a row level would perform worse - all instances would be competing for the same row, that would no longer satisfy the conditions after its lock is released. Also, if instances lock the table for 100ms, and then spend 2 seconds actually performing the task, i believe i will see no performance deterioration from locks till i get to around 20 instances.. and if i really need more than that, i guess i could make them grab more than one task at a time.

Comment: Anyway, if i need a solution that scaleable, i probably wouldn't be using any relational database to coordinate the instances, i would probably go with Redis or some distributed queue service.

Comment: You are right, if all transactions need to update the same row, they have to queue anyway, and `LOCK TABLE` wouldn't make things worse. It was not obvious from the questions that all your upates change the same rows. But then your criticism against relational databases loses its teeth, because no other system can have different concurrent sessions change the same value at the same time consistently.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. This is becoming an off topic discussion, and I hate arguing with you, I hope it doesn’t make me sound ungrateful, but I just wanted to say this is not what I meant.

Comment: I agree that nothing has been invented yet that is better at handling data in general than a relational database. I also agree that no system would allow 2 sessions to modify the same rows at the same time (at least not without grave consequences for everyone)

Comment: The situation here, though, is that all users want the same row till the lock on that row has been released; but after the lock has been released, they want a different row. (As I said, they all want a least recently touched row; once the lock is released, that record becomes most recently touched, not least recently touched)

Comment: Redis lists that I mentioned work in a much simpler way than a transactional database; they are just stacks that allow pushing/pulling from top/bottom. They have no sophistication of a relational database, but at least the way their distribution works they never handle the same element to 2 or more different requests. They are also fast, since they operate on a very simple algorithm, and because they keep all their datasets in memory.

Comment: The problem with them, of course, is that they are not transactional; if one of the instances processing tasks crashes, it might lead to a task being lost from the list for good; so it would require a rather sophisticated extra component that would keep synchronizing the Redis list with another system, which would be an ultimate source of truth.

Comment: Thank you so much for this tip. I had two `UPDATE ... FROM` queries that were very similar and updating rows in a massive table, using the same temp source table. With the default postgres Seq Scan synchronization, both queries were scanning through the same temp source table together and then attempting to make similar updates to the larger table at the same time. By disabling that behavior, each `UPDATE` query does its own scan of the temp source table, causing it to be a bit slower (it only has ~1000 rows) but the deadlock issues are gone!